# AWK Script to read from log file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a requirement to read certain parameters from log file and then update to a database. I am trying to achieve the first part, i.e. to read from log file using awk commands in a shell script

Log file may consists of below lines or more-

```
[2018-05-22T11:35:17,857] [RQST: rqst_3ADE-5439-598D-1B8B | TB: 9000042] - [588455375] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.functions.TestTransactionService - Line 769 - requestType="TESTING",partnerName="Test Merchant 123",testId="123456",lob="TEST1_TO_TEST2",tranType="TEST1",paymentType="P2M",amount="110.00",currency="840",processor="CBN",network="TestSend",responseCode="00", acctNumLastFour="0087",binCountry="USA",binCurr="USD"
[2018-05-22T11:35:17,857] [RQST: rqst_2AEF-2339-598D-1B8B | TB: 9000043] - [588455376] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.functions.TestTransactionService - Line 770 - requestType="TESTING",partnerName="Test Merchant 234",testId="234567",lob="TEST2_TO_TEST3",tranType="TEST2",paymentType="P2M",amount="120.00",currency="850",processor="CBN",network="TestSend",responseCode="00", acctNumLastFour="0087",binCountry="USA",binCurr="USD"
[2018-05-22T11:35:17,857] [RQST: rqst_4EDA-4539-598D-1B8B | TB: 9000044] - [588455377] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.functions.TestTransactionService - Line 771 - requestType="TESTING",partnerName="Test Merchant 345",testId="345678",lob="TEST3_TO_TEST4",tranType="TEST3",paymentType="P2M",amount="130.00",currency="860",processor="CBN",network="TestSend",responseCode="00", acctNumLastFour="0087",binCountry="USA",binCurr="USD"
```

I need to apply filters processor and paymentType and retrieve values of the amount, currency, network and responseCode to variables in a shell script which will be inserted into an Oracle DB table.

I am new to ShellScript and AWK and unable to wrap this. I have tried using

```
awk '/amount/{print}' testAPI.log
```

however, is returning all rows which have amount.

Comment: Is your log actually looking like that? Instead of pasting it and formatting as "Quote" format it as "Code" with the `{}` button (or indent every line with 4 spaces.

Comment: What are you expecting that command to do? `/amount/` means that it should execute the following block if the line contains that string.

Comment: If you just want to print something like `amount="110.00"`, you need to set the field separator to `,`, then loop over the fields with a `for` loop. Check whether the field matches `/^amount=/`, and if it does print that field.

Comment: @Barmar - I want to retrieve the value 110.00 from amount (also from other fields mentioned in the question) to update a DB table

Comment: So when you get to that field, use `split()` to split it at `"` characters, then get the number from the 2nd element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you didn't specify the expected output, here is a template you can tailor for your needs

```
$ awk -F' - ' '{n=split($NF,a,",");
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {split(a[i],b,"="); kv[b[1]]=b[2]}}
     kv["processor"]=="\"CBN\"" 
  && kv["paymentType"]=="\"P2M\""{print kv["amount"],kv["currency"]}' file

"110.00" "840"
"120.00" "850"
"130.00" "860"
```

you can trim the double quotes as well but not sure it's needed as is...

Comment: Thank you, It is returning values, but also returning empty values like below - 

"" ""
"" ""
"" ""
"1.20" "840"
"1.20" "840"
"1.20" "840"
"1.20" "840"
Also, how to grab these in to a variable so that i can insert these in to a db table?

Comment: means some records are missing the variables.  You can `read` the values and insert record by record, but perhaps getting the full extract and batch loading all up will be better (depends on your db/platform/tools).  Perhaps you need to ask another Q for that...

Comment: Thank you @karakfa. Added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493142/retrieve-values-from-log-file-and-update-oracle-db-table to get more details

Comment: How to assign kv["amount"] to a variable in shellscript?

Comment: that value is only visible to `awk` script; print and `read` to a variable in `bash` script.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to "print and read to a variable in Bash script"

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the three entries in the question, below gives you the output you want

it checks if $5 is `paymentType="P2M"` and if $8 is having the value `processor="CBN"` basically, the filter you were looking for, substitute with the required filters you need.

```
cat testAccelAPI.log | grep -i "[RQST: rqst" | cut -d ' ' -f 19 | awk -F, '{ if($5=="paymentType=\"P2M\"" && $8=="processor=\"CBN\"") print $5 "=" $6 "="$7 "="$8 "=" $9 "="$10}' | cut -d= -f 4,6,8,9 | tr = " "
```

Comment: I will try and update if it works. Thanks @Eby Jacob

Comment: sure it did work on my test i did, will wait for your update

Comment: If paymentType or processor doen't really need to be in 5th or 8th column, removing $5 and $8 works as well?

Comment: try the same script, since i did a cut with space delimiter of the line stream, it occurs to be at 5th and 8th column after the `cut`

Comment: if you share a decent size of the log and the insert sql, i can help you construct the sql aswell as the output of this shell script

Comment: Thank you @Eby Jacob. It worked in my test log file. When i hit actual log file it seems to be not working as there are other bunch of info in the actual log file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171579/discussion-between-chilbud-and-eby-jacob).